# Why isn't my text-align property applying to my span?

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
    <style>
    .right {
      text-align: right;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <span class="right">test</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want 'test' to be displayed at right, but it didn't work. If I change span to div, it works. Why is that? I want  span, but not div. In the following example, I want 'name'  to be displayed at the right of the page, but at the same line as 'age'. But the 'span' tag doesn't do the job.

```
<span>age</span>  <span class="right">name</span>
```

Comment: it's because the default `display` style of tags, div have `display: block` which gets the entire line (100% of available width) and span have `dispaly: inline` by default which means the content inside it define the width, so text-align to a span take no effect if you not set the width of the span to a greater value than the content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<span>` element is an inline container and it occupies the space based on content. Where as `<div>` is a block element and it occupies the parent container fully. So if you want it to work with `<span>`

- you can set the `display: block`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
        <style>
        .right {
          text-align: right;
          display: block;
        }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>

        <span class="right">test</span>
      </body>
    </html>
```

- You can use `float` instead of `text-align` with span

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
    <style>
    .right {
      float: right;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <span class="right">test</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Same for the second example:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
        <style>
        .right {
          float: right;
        }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>

        <span>age</span>  <span class="right">name</span>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. What't the difference between text-align and float?

Comment: @marlon. float moves the container to the right but text-align moves the text within the container to the right

Answer (score 1):

`span` is an inline element. Its width is that of its content. So while the content of the `span` is being aligned to the right, it's unnoticeable.

`div`s, on the other hand, are block elements, and will span the width of the container.

if you want to align the `span` to the right, you should to wrap it in a `div` and apply `text-align:right` to it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
    <style>
    .right {
      text-align: right;
      width:100%;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="right"><span>test</span></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because a `<div>` has a default `display` property of `block`, but `<span>` has a default `display` property of `inline`.

Change your `.right` class to include `display: block;` and it will work for both.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
    <style>
    .right {
      display: block;
      text-align: right;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <span class="right">test</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

`<span>` documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span